# Problem with bibliography in Ph.D template

Tags: bibliographies, errors, templates

I am currently working with the Ph.D. template available in [this link](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis). I, however, am having trouble with the bibliography. I have a .bib file in which I store my references and is in the same folder as the main.tex file. The last lines of the main code are as follow

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

I have tried to add my own .bib file, bilioFile.bib as

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\bibliography{biblioFile}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, if I try to compile the main file, I get the following error

```
   LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 326.


! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.327 \bibliography
                   {biblioFile}
?
```

I have no clue of how to solve it. I am attaching a screenshot of the folder.
[image]

I will appreciate any guidance on how to fix this.

Best regards.

EDIT: I have changed the bibliography as suggested in the comments as

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\addbibresource{biblioFile.bib}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

And now, the error looks like

```
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 326.


! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.328 \addbibresource
                     {biblioFile.bib}
?
```

I don't know if this will be helpful, but I am using texworks and I cannot compile the file using  biblatex, only pdfLaTeX and bibTeX

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. Then we know exactly what you're doing and have a better chance to provide help.

Comment: To me it looks kinda like you're trying to use both bibtex and biblatex at the same time. Please only use one.

Comment: Use `\addbibresource{biblioFile.bib}` in the preamble instead of `\bibliography{biblioFile}`. The template use `biblatex`

Comment: @SimonDispa I am afraid I have used `\addbibresource{biblioFile.bib}` and i still get an error. However, this time has changed to `! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.328 \addbibresource
                     {biblioFile.bib}
? ` @daleif I don't know how to provide a minimal example without attaching a file. I would have to upload the main and the bib file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Put  `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}`  replacing the line `\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}` in the template.

(2) Add the command `\nocite{*}` to list all entries from the `.bib` file

(3) Compile `newmain.tex`: (pdflatex +biber +pdflatex +pdflatex)

(3) Now replace `\addbibresource{example.bib}` for `\addbibresource{biblioFile.bib}` and compile again. It should produce the list of all your entries.

(4) If `biber` found errors look at `newmain.blg` with a text editor.

This is `newmain.tex`

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt, english,singlespacing]{MastersDoctoralThesis} %

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % USE this instead <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\addbibresource{example.bib} % The filename of the bibliography <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\nocite{*} % list all entries

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image: a]